Is there an R function, to be able to split a single row of data into multiple rows
Ive seen similar questions but none seem to quite fit what I am trying to do.
I have a large database built of responses from a goolge forms questionaire. To try and manipulate the data better (in ways I know how). I want to convert the long row of questions and answers into single rows per question, (I have about 30 questions). Each question is duplicated to have the response value, and a notes field.
An example of what my data looks like and what I want to convert it to is below:



ID
Species
Name
Date
First Question?
First Question?
Second Question
Second Question




1
Cat
Dan
22/07/2024
2
NA
2
NA


2
Dog
Ed
22/07/2024
1
Not normal
1
NA


3
Bird
Ben
22/07/2024
0
Seen difference
1
NA


4
Bird
Dan
22/07/2024
2
NA
0
NA






ID
Species
Name
Date
Question?
Answer
Question notes?




1
Cat
Dan
22/07/2024
First Question?
2
NA


1
Cat
Dan
22/07/2024
Second Question?
2
NA


2
Dog
Ed
22/07/2024
First Question?
1
Not normal


2
Dog
Ed
22/07/2024
Second Question?
1
NA


3
Bird
Ben
22/07/2024
First Question?
0
Seen difference


3
Bird
Ben
22/07/2024
Second Question?
1
NA


4
Bird
Dan
22/07/2024
First Question?
2
NA


4
Bird
Dan
22/07/2024
Second Question?
0
NA



Thank you

This is some version of tidyr::pivot_longer() (there are also ways to do it in base R, but the pivot_longer() syntax is usually simplest)

Someone may come along and answer, but the steps to do this are probably (1) rename the columns to unique values that are useful in the next step (e.g. "Q1_answer", "Q1_note", "Q2_answer", "Q2_note" -- you probably need to refer to the columns by numeric index since the names aren't unique); (2) use pivot_longer to pivot the columns, probably with names_sep="_"
